# In Typescript, is there a way to make function parameters typing mandatory

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-eslint

I'm working on a big project with JS and TS files and sometimes there are no types on Typescript functions.

Since we want to use typescript to type things I would like to have a way to make function parameters mandatory with typescript CLI or ESLint, is this possible ?

Did not find anything on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TSConfig option [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) will ensure that parameters are specified and not assumed to be `any`.

[`noImplicitReturns`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns) will also help for return types.

Comment: Thanks ! Yep thought it was about all "any" but the "implicit" makes it explicit !